# Sonicwall Enhanced With One-To-One NAT, Firewall Blocking Everything

Tags: sonicwall

just migrated from a Sonicwall TZ180 (Standard) to a Sonicwall TZ200 (Enhanced). Everything is working except the firewall rules are blocking everything. All hosts are online, and being assigned correct ip addresses. I can browse the internet on the hosts.

I am using one-to-one NAT translating public ip addresses to private.

```
  64.87.28.98 -> 192.168.1.2
  64.87.28.99 -> 192.168.1.3
  etc
```

First order of business is to get ping working. My rule is in the new firewall is (FROM WAN to LAN):

```
 SOURCE    DESTINATION                SERVICE    ACTION      USERS
 ANY       192.168.1.2-192.168.1.6    PING       ALLOW       ALL
```

This should be working, but not. I even tried changing the destination to the public ip addresses, but still no luck.

```
 SOURCE    DESTINATION                 SERVICE    ACTION      USERS
 ANY       64.87.28.98-64.87.28.106    PING       ALLOW       ALL
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is ANY set to 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0? Is PING set to ICMP (1)?

Comment: Have you tried sniffing the traffic inside the network to see if pings are coming through but something else isn't working?

Comment: The problem after a few hours of trouble shooting wasn't the firewall rules, but NAT Policy. That's the short answer.